# Angularjs ui-view not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

ui-view is not working and there is no error shown. What did I miss? Please help me out and make this work.

This is my **index.html** which is the main template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="LoginPage.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Project">
<div class="mainbox">
    <div class="loginmsg">
        <div class="row text-center">
                <p id="title">
                    <b>Movie Baba</b>
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here LoginPage.js which I have included in the script tag is the controller for **LoginPage.html**

**app.js** is the config file which contains the states.

```
var Project = angular.module('Project', [ 'ui.router' ]);
Project.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $stateProvider.state('login',{
                    url : '/login',
                    templateUrl : 'LoginPage.html',
                    controller : 'LoginCtrl'
            })
    });
```

The following is the **LoginPage.html** which I'm trying to load/render using ui-view in **index.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Username : </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" ng-model="user.username" name="username" maxlength="50"required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and [`ui.router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) are different libraries.

You should be importing the right script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

(Instead of `/angular-route.js`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Project">
  <div class="mainbox">
    <div class="loginmsg">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <p id="title">
          <b>Movie Baba</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="LoginPage.html">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Username : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" ng-model="user.username" name="username" maxlength="50" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script>
    var Project = angular.module('Project', ['ui.router']);
    Project.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

      $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'LoginPage.html'
      })
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you also load up ui-router in addition to loading Angular:

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

When creating a link with UI-Router, you will use ui-sref:for example:

```
<body ng-app="Project">
<div class="mainbox">
    <div class="loginmsg">
        <div class="row text-center">
                <p id="title">
                    <b>Movie Baba</b>
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="login">login</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The href will be generated from this and you want this to point to a certain state of your application.